# Show that if $T$ is injective or surjective, then $T$ is an isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over a field $K$ and $T : V \to W$ be a linear map

Suppose that $V = W$. Show that if $T$ is injective or surjective, then $T$ is an
isomorphism

Injective: $\ker(T)=\{0\}$, therefore $\{v \in V:T(v)=0\}=\{0\}$. Thus a one to one mapping from $0$ to $0$.
Since $V=W$, we have the same dimension, therefore the same mapping, therefore for all points there exists a one to one mapping.

Surjective: $\mathrm{Im}(T)=V$, since the image is the whole set then, $w\in V:T(v)=w$ is the whole of the codomain, since they are equivalent, we have a one to one mapping from the domain to the codomain, hence a bijection.

Does this logic make sense or is a good enough answer, have I missed anything.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work for infinite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: Extending Nishant's comment: The last statement in each Injective/Surjective part is very wrong for infinite dimensional spaces. But if $V=W$ are of finite dimensional, then they become true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have 
$$T\;\text{is injective}\iff \ker T=\{0\}$$
and

$$T\;\text{is surjective}\iff \operatorname{im} T=V$$
and we see by the rank-nullity theorem (in finite dimensional space) that

$$T\;\text{is injective}\iff T\;\text{is surjective}\iff T\;\text{is bijective}$$

Comment: You're welcome.